# Set language of GTK Buttons to a different language - Linux - Python

Tags: python, linux, gtk3

How can I set the default language of the Gtk3 Stock Buttons to another language?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en
```

But:

```
import locale
from pprint import pprint

pprint(locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL))
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_EN.utf8')
```

response:

```
('de_DE', 'UTF-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tp_tools.py", line 41, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_EN.utf8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Working on Linux Mint 18 with Python 2.7 and Gtk3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`en_EN.utf8` and also `en_EN` is no valid locale (contrary to `de_DE`). You can list your installed locales with `locale -a` in your shell.

A correct locale would be for example `en_US` or `en_GB`. And a correct instruction would be `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `gi.repository.Gtk` calls `Gtk.init()` while being imported, and after that it is nearly impossible to make any changes to localization. Furthermore, setting the locale to hardcoded strings makes your application almost unportable, since the only locale you can assume to exist is "C", which doesn't even include UTF-8 support.

The only solution I found so far is by setting the environment variable 'LANGUAGE' before any import of GLib modules, which is given priority by gettext and does not need to have an encoding definition appended to it ([more information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html)). This works for me:

```
import os
os.environ["LANGUAGE"] = "en"
```

PS: Stop using Python 2, it's outdated.
PPS: Gtk+ 3 stock buttons are deprecated.